# Is a bad programming practice instantiating a class and not saving it in a object?

Tags: c#, oop, instantiation

What I'm trying to say is that: when you instantiate a class you can use the methods of that class using the access operator (`.`) after the object, but if you only want to use one method of the class and only one time? The expression inside this click event (code below) would work, but is this method considered a good/bad programming practice?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AboutBox1().ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Why is `ShowDialog` not static?

Comment: @TimSchmelter just to play devil's advocate -  it could access default private `AboutBox1` state.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The method `ShowDialog` in a Form is not static. Try your self adding a AboutBox to a project and using `AboutBox1().ShowDialog();` and it will return an error. So I think you question simply doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The `AboutBox1` class might be a reusable third-party class that doesn't offer a static `ShowDialog` method.

Comment: @Zignd: `public static new void ShowDialog()
        {
            Form f = new AboutBox1();
            f.ShowDialog();
        }` However, you haven't mentioned that it's the `ShowDialog` from `Form`, that's why i've asked. My comment was also meant more general.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: ...`f.Dispose();`, and all of that within a clean `try`...`finally`, possibly. This looks a lot like WinForms. Just in case :-)

Comment: If AboutBox1 is derived from System.Form, then I would frown on that usage because the form will not be automatically disposed after it is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the object doesn't need disposing, there is nothing wrong with using it that way.

An example that shows the benefit of creating an object that only lasts for the duration of the statement, is using a `StringBuilder` to create a string:

```
string tag =
  new StringBuilder()
  .Append("<div id=\"")
  .Append(id)
  .Append("\">")
  .ToString();
```

As the `Append` methods return the `StringBuilder` instance they are chainable, until you call `ToString` and you end up with just the string and the `StringBuilder` goes away.

Comment: Guffa just to confirm if I got it correctly if I attribute an instance of a class to a object of different type the resources used by that instance is released? Also, the usage of a reference type object of the same class that was instantiated would release the resources automatically? Or even using it I would have to use `objClass.Dispose()`?

Comment: @Zignd: Calm down, this is not a chat. :) You mean when the `ToString` method returns a `string` instead of the `StringBuilder`? In the example the only reference to the `StringBuilder` is the one that is passed from call to call, and when the `ToString` method returns a `string` instead, there is no reference to the `StringBuilder` any more, and it's left for the garbage collector to clean up. The `Dispose` method only exists in classes that need it, most objects can just be left without a reference to them, and the garbage collector takes care of them.

Answer (score 9):

> but is this method considered a good/bad programming practice?

Nothing bad in it, if you are not going to use the instance of form `AboutBox1`, later in your code.

The above is also used for calling non-static method from static method like:

```
class MyTest
{
    public void InstanceMethod()
    {
    }

    public static void StaticMethod()
    {
        new MyTest().InstanceMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have shown is not problematic, unless you are creating an instance that needs to be disposed of after use.

If the instance needs to be disposed of, use a `using` block:

```
using (var aboutBox = new AboutBox()) {
    aboutBox.ShowDialog();
}
```

Otherwise, the direct member call after the constructor without any lasting variable/reference is fine:

```
new AboutBox().ShowDialog();
```

Comment: O. R. Mapper so based on what you said if I decide to use `new AboutBox().ShowDialog();` the instance will still remain in memory even if it's inside an event? Shouldn't it release the resources after the end of the events?

Comment: @Zignd: Managed resources are released automatically at some point after the instance has gone out of scope - in this case, at the end of the event handler. However, unmanaged resources (such as Win API window handles, in case this is WinForms) may remain blocked, hence you should call `Dispose` on the object when you're done using it.

Comment: @Zignd: Maybe because I was slow at writing, and most visitors just read the first or at most the first two answers at all? And then, Guffa's answer is very good, too, as he/she makes a good point about the chained calling.

Comment: +1 @O.R.Mapper, thats a pretty valid reason to hold the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually **it depends** on the context or purpose of your class.

If you are not using it anywhere a reference is not necessary